# Look UP formula in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this formula in VBA but getting a type mismatch error

```
LastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(2, 1 / --Len(Range("L23:L9000")) > 0, _
          Application.WorksheetFunction.Row(Range("L23:L9000")))
```

Kindly help what is wrong, and this formula works fine in Excel

Answer (score 0):

What is your working Excel Formula for which you are trying to reproduce in VBA?

It seems you are perhaps converting an array formula, which may not convert into VBA. For that you can use:

```
Application.Evaluate("<Your working Excel formula in here>")
```

I see two glaring errors:

1)  `Application.WorksheetFunction.Row` is not a valid worksheet function. You could try `Range("L23:L9000").Row` or `Range("L23:L9000").Rows`, depending on what you meant to use.

2) Similarly, you cannot use `Len(Range("L23:L9000"))`, since Len expects a scalar value and not a range.

Comment: Thanks for your help